# What is the best way to check if something exists with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Some one told me rowCount not safe so I like to ask it here, I have 2 examples and like to know what is the safest and nice way to check if something exists?

```
$sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM users WHERE username = 'administrator'";
$result = $db->prepare($sql);
$result->execute();
echo $result->fetchColumn() ? 'true' : 'false';
```

or

```
$sql = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = ?";
$result = $db->prepare($sql);
$result->execute(array('administrator'));
echo $result->rowCount() ? 'true' : 'false';
```

Comment: If you look at the manual there is a note on the `rowcount` function about this exact issue. `For most databases, PDOStatement::rowCount() does not return the number of rows affected by a SELECT statement. Instead, use PDO::query() to issue a SELECT COUNT(*) statement with the same predicates as your intended SELECT statement, then use PDOStatement::fetchColumn() to retrieve the number of rows that will be returned. Your application can then perform the correct action.`-http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php (example #2)

Comment: @kamalpal getting the number of rows and checking for existence are two different tasks.

Comment: @YourCommonSense agreed, but the approach would be same.

Comment: @kamalpal not in the slightest. Not to mention that the answer you linked to suggests you to run 2 queries instead of one, which is a nonsense.

Comment: @YourCommonSense The answer I've linked, shows how to get rows count using PDO, which I think also an approach to check existence (saty has used the same approach) and it's done in single query `$nRows = $pdo->query('select count(*) from blah')->fetchColumn();`, However I've noticed this would be just one approach and there could be more, close vote taken back.

Comment: Both suggested dupe answer and Saty's answer explicitly suggest you to run an EXTRA count(*) query **in addition** to a query that selects the actual data. Which makes no sense at all.

Comment: @chris85 even after a year, still nothing huh?

Comment: @Fred-ii- Guess they're not using links.. :(.

Comment: @chris85 *Nope*

Answer (score 3):

The best way to check it with `prepare` and  `fetchColumn`

> SELECT COUNT(*) statement with the same predicates as your intended
>   SELECT statement, then use [**PDOStatement::fetchColumn()**](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) to retrieve the
>   number of rows that will be returned.

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE username = ?";// use `COUNT(*)`
$result = $db->prepare($sql);
$result->execute(array('administrator'));
echo $result->fetchColumn() ? 'true' : 'false';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE username = 'administrator' LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Using rowCount() isn't unsafe, but just improper.

The #1 rule when working with databases is

## Always select the exact data you need.

with as less post-processing as possible.

So if you need to check whatever data for existence, then **ask your database to check** and then fetch the result.

However, you have to keep in mind that there are 2 possible scenarios:

1. In case you indeed need to check wherever something exists in a database, but don't need the data, then (assuming username has an unique index on it):

   ```
   $sql = "SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE username = ?";
   $result = $db->prepare($sql);
   $result->execute(array('administrator'));
   echo $result->fetchColumn() ? 'true' : 'false';
   ```
2. But often you need the data itself if it happens to be found. In this case you **just select that data**:

   ```
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?";
   $result = $db->prepare($sql);
   $result->execute(array('administrator'));
   $user = $result->fetch();
   echo $user ? 'true' : 'false';
   ```

I am stressing on it because the wording of the other answer suggests that you have to run 2 queries: one to check the existence and one to get the data, which is a nonsense.

As of the `rowCount()` method - [you need it too seldom to talk about](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#count).

Comment: thanks and also for the link, it help me alot :)